# LevenshteinSim() Approximate string matching

Tags: string, matching, approximate

I am using `levenshteinSim()` to do the approximate string matching. I am facing a problem
here is what my data look like

```
string = "Mitchell" 
stringvector = c("Ray Mitchell", "Mitchell Dough","Juila Mitch")
```

.
I want the algorithm to match only second part of the Stringvector, not the first half..How do i do it. I really appreciate your help. And how do I use weighing schema?
Thanks
Kothavari

Comment: Is this in R? Or doesn't the language matter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to preprocess the data to just pull out the second part of the string and use the algo on that.

Other people seem to do some preproessing first. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683380/techniques-for-finding-near-duplicate-records)