# Similarity measure for Strings in Python

Tags: python, similarity, measure

I want to measure the similarity between two words. The idea is to read a text with OCR and check the result for keywords.
The function I'm looking for should compare two words and return the similarity in %. So comparing a word with itself should be 100% similar.
I wrote a function on my own and compared char by char and returned the number of matches in ratio to the length. But the Problem is that

```
wordComp('h0t',hot')
0.66
wordComp('tackoverflow','stackoverflow')
0
```

But intuitive both examples should have very high similarity >90%. Adding the Levenstein-Distance

```
import nltk
nltk.edit_distance('word1','word2')
```

in my function will increase the second result up to 92% but the first result is still not good.

I already found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044112/how-to-measure-similarity-between-strings) for "R" and it would be possible to use this functions with `rpy2` or use `agrepy` as another approach. But I want to make the program more and less sensitive by changing the benchmark for acceptance (Only accept matches with similarity > x%).

Is there another good measure I could use or do you have any ideas to improve my function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just use difflib. This function I got from an answer some time ago has served me well:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

print (similar('tackoverflow','stackoverflow'))
print (similar('h0t','hot'))

0.96
0.666666666667
```

You could easily append the function or wrap it in another function to account for different degrees of similarities, like so, passing a third argument:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b, c):
    sim = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    if sim > c: 
        return sim

print (similar('tackoverflow','stackoverflow', 0.9))
print (similar('h0t','hot', 0.9))

0.96
None
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. This helps me with the first problem but the problem with short words is still open unanswered. Any other ideas on that?

Comment: Im not quite sure why you want a higher value for the three letter word. You say that intuitively you expected a higher similarity. Strictly speaking, out of three characters one is different between the strings, which makes them 66% similar. Can you elaborate on what your expected outcome should be and why?

Comment: I don't know what the exact outcome should. The point that makes me thing of a higher score is if you compare h0t and hxt than in an intuitive way h0t is closer to hot than hxt since 0 and o are nearly the same. Just imagine if this where handwritten you wouldn't really mark h0t as wrong but hxt is clearly.

Comment: Well yea, they are aestetically similar, I dont know of any way to test for that. That is quite subjective as well, isnt it? For all intents and purposes x and o and 0 are equally dissimilar to one another.

Comment: I just thought about the following "quick and dirty" fix: Just map digits to chars with a fixed mapping (0->o, 5->s,3->E,9->g,...). Since I'm searching for real words a zero or five or what ever number should never be part of the keyword.

Comment: Yes, that could work. Just out of curiosity: Would you adjust for that in the similarity ratio by a factor or would you just take a 5 for an s, a 9 for a g etc?

Comment: just take the digits and map them to the characters. It works surprisingly well. I've added some more lines of code and other rules. For example a regulation therm -0.1 for each mapped digit for the ratio or a capital "i" in the middle of a word will be mapped to "L" and so on... I'll share my result when all rules are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code. try it. I defined a str3 for those occasions that length of two comparing string(str1 and str2) is not equal. the code is in while loop for exiting  use k input.

```
k=1
cnt=0
str3=''
while not k==-1:
    str1=input()
    str2=input()
    k=int(input())

    if len(str1)>len(str2):
        str3=str1[0:len(str2)]
        for j in range(0,len(str3)):
            if str3[j]==str2[j]:
                cnt+=1
        print((cnt/len(str1)*100))

    elif len(str1)<len(str2):
        str3=str2[0:len(str1)]
        for j in range(0,len(str2)):
            if str3[j]==str1[j]:
                cnt+=1
        print((cnt/len(str2)*100))

    else:
        for j in range(0,len(str2)):
            if str2[j]==str1[j]:
                cnt+=1
        print((cnt/len(str1)*100))
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your code. This looks like what I have tried in the first place. You get similar results with this function like I did. The main problem I see is that you'll lose a lot of information when you cut the string `str3=str2[0:len(str1)]`.