# Replace entire expression that contains a specific string

Tags: string, r, expression, gsub

I have data frame that has a column with large number of file names like:

```
d <- c("harry11_scott80_norm.avi","harry11_norm.avi","harry11_scott80_lpf.avi", 
       "joel51_lpf.avi","rich82_joel51_lpf.avi")
```

I want R to replace all expressions with two people names like `harry11_scott80_norm.avi` with the expression `incongruent` and all the ones with single person name like `harry11_norm.avi` with `congruent`. I could use `gsub` to do that:

```
dd <- gsub("harry11_scott80_norm.avi", "incongruent", d)
```

but I got a lot of those names, so it would be a very clunky solution. So ideally I want to replace the ENTIRE expression that contains strings like `_scott80_` with "incongruent". I thought that `gsub` can do this, but when I run it:

```
dd <- gsub("_scott80_", "incongruent", d)
```

it returns with `harry11incongruentnorm.avi`, which is obviously because it simply replace the exact string match. I recon there is some way to tell `gsub` to replace expression entirely that contains selected string, but I can't find it.

There was a question [In R, how do I replace a string that contains a certain pattern with another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302669/in-r-how-do-i-replace-a-string-that-contains-a-certain-pattern-with-another-str), but I am not sure how to use  `agrep` in this context.

---

**EDIT:** Side bonus question - based on @GSee answer, is there any function that allows you to pass a list of strings that you want to replace? For example, `gsub(c(".*_scott80_.*", ".*_harry11_.*"), "incongruent", d)` won't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's one way

```
> gsub(".*_scott80_.*", "incongruent", d)
[1] "incongruent"           "harry11_norm.avi"      "incongruent"          
[4] "joel51_lpf.avi"        "rich82_joel51_lpf.avi"
```

Or with `grep`

```
> d[grep("_scott80_", d)] <- "incongruent"
> d
[1] "incongruent"           "harry11_norm.avi"      "incongruent"          
[4] "joel51_lpf.avi"        "rich82_joel51_lpf.avi"
```

---

To address your edit, I believe this will do it (using `|` to mean "or")

```
gsub(".*(_scott80_|_harry11_).*", "incongruent", d)
```

Of course, you don't have any strings in `d` that match `"_harry11_"`

Comment: Wow, that was VERY quick, thanks @GSee. The one which uses `gsub` fits my purpose better because it allows me to create separate column with new expressions.

Answer (score 5):

If your filenames are all of the same format, that is those with two names i.e `harry11_scott80_norm.avi` *always* have two underscores, and those with one name i.e. `harry11_norm.avi` *always* have one underscore, you can quickly use something like this to rename your files:

```
d = gsub(".*_.*_.*", "incongruent", d)
> d
[1] "incongruent"      "harry11_norm.avi" "incongruent"      "joel51_lpf.avi"  
[5] "incongruent"

d =gsub(".*_.*","congruent",d)
> d
[1] "incongruent" "congruent"   "incongruent" "congruent"   "incongruent"
```