# R: gsub with conditional word?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-mining, gsub

In a column within my dataframe, I would like to replace any level that contains the word "tech" in it (fintech, fin tech, agtech, tech, etc) with "technology". How can I do this with gsub?

I'd also like any string with the word "online" or "marketplace" in it to be replaced with "consumer internet"

Comment: The first one is just a straight subset and replace - `df$col[grepl("tech",df$col)] <- "technology"` as per previous questions like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275614/replace-entire-expression-that-contains-a-specific-string - which also covers the second multiple string logic combining with `|` as well. `df$col[grepl("online|marketplace",df$col)] <- "consumer internet"`

Comment: very helpful, thank you!