# R: grepl with NA's

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
file = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), col1 = c("Red", "Blue", "CCC", "Yellow", "Orange"), col2 = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "Red"))


  id   col1 col2
1  1    Red  AAA
2  2   Blue  BBB
3  3    CCC  CCC
4  4 Yellow  DDD
5  5 Orange  Red
```

**For all cells that contain %LIKE% "CCC" or %LIKE% "Red", I would like to replace them with NA.** The end result should look something like this:

```
  id   col1 col2
1  1    NA  AAA
2  2   Blue  BBB
3  3   NA   NA
4  4 Yellow  DDD
5  5 Orange  NA
```

I found a similar post ([Replace entire expression that contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275614/replace-entire-expression-that-contains-a-specific-string)) and tried to apply the logic presented there to my question:

```
step1 = file[grep("CCC", file)] <- "NA"
step2 = step1[grep("Red", step1)] <- "NA"
```

However, I don't think this is working - all I get is an "NA" output.

Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?

Comment: `replace(file, file == "CCC" | file == "Red", NA)` or `is.na(file) <- file == "Red"; is.na(file) <- file == "CCC"`

Comment: @ Ritchie Sacramento: thank you so much for your reply! Is it possible to modify this code so that its %LIKE% Red and %LIKE% CCC?

Comment: `replace(file, sapply(file, \`%like%\`, c("Red|CCC")), NA)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ifelse` along with `%in%`:

```r
file$col1 <- ifelse(file$col1 %in% c("CCC", "Red"), NA, file$col1)
file$col2 <- ifelse(file$col2 %in% c("CCC", "Red"), NA, file$col2)
```

For a substring match, use `grepl`:

```
<!-- language: r -->

file$col1 <- ifelse(grepl("CCC|Red", file$col1), NA, file$col1)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! Is it possible to modify this code so that its %LIKE% Red and %LIKE% CCC?